# navigation drawer y webview kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragment, navigation-drawer

en android studio se puede crear un Activity Navigation Drawer por defecto y mi problema es que quiero mostrar un Webview en uno de los fragments de navigation drawer,puse el webview en el fragment_home.xml pero no se donde poner el codigo del webview para que se muestre en el fragment_home [image]
estos son los que se crean por defecto y alguien me puede explicar donde poner el codigo del webview para mostrarlo en el fragment_home y como hacerlo
se aprecia la ayuda, soy nuevo en esto

Answer (score 0):

1. En la carpeta res->layout abres fragment_home.xml y cambias simplemente el TextView con WebView.
2. En la carpeta java->ui->home abres el HomeFragment.kt y tienes que añadir webViewClient.

ejemplo de fragment_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Aplica los cambios correspondientes en onCreateView de HomeFragment.kt

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val myWebView: WebView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)
       
        myWebView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.TUPAGINAWEB.com")
        myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

        return root
    }
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias , me sirvio mucho